# If div doesn't have img tag, add a "no image" img to div (Javascript or Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, prepend

I'm trying to prepend an img tag to a div element if the div element doesn't have an img tag already. What is the best method to use? I'd like to see the answer both in javascript and jquery so it will help me learn but either one is fine.

I've made a few jquery attempts using the .not() and the .empty() but I feel I'm not thinking correctly about it.

Comment: Give us your jQuery attempts. We will add ice to it. :) Add some code

Comment: there can also be pure CSS solution

Comment: CSS solution? Really???, I'm definitely interested in seeing that.

Comment: I said *can*. It depends on actual problem. For example sometimes you need to present user some noimage picture before real one is uploaded.  In this case you can set it as background. If however you *really* need `img` tag, then this is JS job.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
if($('#your_div').find('img').length==0){
   $('#your_div').prepend('<img src="img/your_image.jpg" />');
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZHcxS/)

Answer (score 3):

Pure javascript is not so elegant as JQuery

```
var imgexists = false;
for (var i = 0; i < mydiv.children.length; i++) {
    if (mydiv.children[i].tagName.toLowerCase() == "img") {
        imgexists = true;
        break;
    };
};

if (!imgexists) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "some/path.png";
    if (mydiv.children.length > 0) {
        mydiv.appendChild(img, mydiv.firstChild);
    } else {
        mydiv.appendChild(img);
    };
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, you have great jQuery solutions so I will propose pure JS version:

```
var div = document.getElementById('div');

if (!div.querySelector('img')) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = 'image.png';
    div.insertBefore(img, div.firstChild);
}
```

Tests: http://jsfiddle.net/9V2HR/

As you can see vanilla JS is almost as short as jQuery code in this case.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($("#myId img").length === 0) {
    $("#myId").append("<img src=\"https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png\" />");
}
```

[Use jQuery length](http://api.jquery.com/length/)

Don't bother with a pure JavaScript solution - it will be unnecessarily complex and possibly prone to cross-browser incompatibility

Answer (score 1):

use `length` and `find` the `img` tag...yes prepend..no do other sttuff

using jquery

```
if($('#divID').find('img').length > 0) {
   //img present so do other stuff 
}else{
   var img=$('<img />',{src:"imgsrc.jpg"});
  $('#divID').prepend(img)
};
```

Comment: `I'd like to see the answer both in javascript and jquery so it will help me learn but either one is fine.`